# Flask/SQLAlchemy/Docker Is there a better way to handle what I think is a circular dependancy? Full github project included

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue where I can't get my db object to work in various routes in my app

I've spent a good 6 hours on this today and tried various options including appfactory patterns, extension loading, blueprints and more and no matter what approach I take I am just getting stumped.

I want to keep the blueprint pattern I have, this is key, yet at the base level, I just can't get the `.db` to load.

This is the full error:

```
$ sudo docker-compose up --build
WARNING: The UID variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Building website
Step 1/10 : FROM python:3.7.2-alpine
 ---> bb1ccaa5880c
Step 2/10 : MAINTAINER (info to live here)
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c86eafc23e13
Step 3/10 : ENV INSTALL_PATH /logrr
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 18de4002edc2
Step 4/10 : RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 78996ea3714d
Step 5/10 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf253a9bfe18
Step 6/10 : WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 04e1a0092af0
Step 7/10 : COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e96a1b830b07
Step 8/10 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 114d0dcd7eb0
Step 9/10 : COPY . .
 ---> cdc705c36e0d
Step 10/10 : CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:9000 --access-logfile - "logrr.app:create_app()"
 ---> Running in dbbcb2fa0541
Removing intermediate container dbbcb2fa0541
 ---> 69b7e8cba951
Successfully built 69b7e8cba951
Successfully tagged logrr_website:latest
Recreating logrr_website_1 ... done
Attaching to logrr_website_1
website_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
website_1  |   File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 10, in <module>
website_1  |     sys.exit(run())
website_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
website_1  |     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
website_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run
website_1  |     super(Application, self).run()
website_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
website_1  |     Arbiter(self).run()
website_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 60, in __init__
website_1  |     self.setup(app)
website_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 120, in setup
website_1  |     self.app.wsgi()
website_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
website_1  |     self.callable = self.load()
website_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
website_1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
website_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
website_1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
website_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
website_1  |     __import__(module)
website_1  |   File "/logrr/logrr/app.py", line 3, in <module>
website_1  |     from logrr.blueprints.register import register
website_1  |   File "/logrr/logrr/blueprints/register/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
website_1  |     from logrr.blueprints.register.views import register
website_1  |   File "/logrr/logrr/blueprints/register/views.py", line 4, in <module>
website_1  |     from logrr.models import User, Post, Org
website_1  |   File "/logrr/logrr/models.py", line 2, in <module>
website_1  |     from logrr.app import db
website_1  | ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'logrr.app' (/logrr/logrr/app.py)
logrr_website_1 exited with code 1
```

I have the full code ready to be run via docker-compose here:
https://github.com/therealrobster/bdIssue

You can run it via the standard `sudo docker-compose up --build`  I have it set to `localhost:9000` at present.

For some reason when I try and access the db models I get errors like `ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'logrr.app' (/logrr/logrr/app.py)`

Can anyone look at the code and tell me what I'm doing wrong please?  6 hours of banging head on desk and I'm at my whits end.

Thank you

Comment: Please post enough code to demonstrate the problem here, rather than on some external site. That ensures that people who might benefit from seeing this problem and (hopefully) its resolution won't suffer from a stale link.

Comment: I guess I am posting the whole code structure at github as it would be hard to see it in code blocks here.  I think there's a circular reference issue but I'm a bit new at this to be sure.  By showing the full structure at github it will allow people to see the full thing

Comment: can you add full stacktrace ?

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation thank you I'll add it below in another comment where there's room.  (EDIT) Added to OP

Comment: @robster don't add in comment. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56371262/edit) your question and add it there

Comment: the problem is in your [`models.py`](https://github.com/therealrobster/bdIssue/blob/master/logrr/logrr/models.py) it is importing `db` from `logrr.app` but the `db` is present in `logrr.extensions` .

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation we found it at the same time!  Thank you.  I really appreciate you looking into it.  ALL day I spent (on and off) and it was that simple.  Much appreciate your help.  If you answer, I can mark yours as the correct answer if you wish?

Comment: My understanding was that as I was calling the extensions from app.py it would be available from app.py.  I was wrong of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your `models.py` it is importing `db` from `logrr.app` but the `db` is present in `logrr.extensions`